# A conjecture relating to the limit of a sequence of matrix determinants

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, determinant

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence. We define the sequence $(b_n)$ to be $b_n=\det(A)$ where $A$ is a square matrix of order $n$ such that
$$A_{1,1}=a_1,\dots,A_{1,n}=a_n \\
\vdots\\ A_{n,1}=a_{n^2-n+1},\dots,A_{n,n}=a_{n^2}
.$$

I conjecture that if $(a_n)$ converges to a real number (or maybe even bounded) then $(b_n)$ converges to zero. The reason for this conjecture is simple. It seems to be the "limit version" of the fact that if you have a square matrix with all the entries being the same then the determinant is zero.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don’t quite like your analogy, as we certainly will never have all entries the same. However, given $\epsilon$, there is $N$ so that for $n>N$, the entries of the *last two rows* of the $n\times n$ matrix will be within $\epsilon$ of one another. Think about a row operation to get the last row with the absolute value of its entries $<\epsilon$. But I don’t see a universal upper bound on the $n$ cofactors of those entries. Do you?

Comment: In light of Alex Ravsky's counterexample below, the best way I can think of to fix this conjecture is to say that if $(a_n) \in \ell^2$, then $b_n \rightarrow 0$ by [Hadamard's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality) (since eventually the norm of every row after the first will be small if $(a_n) \in \ell^2$).

Comment: @MichaelJesurum What does $ \ell^2$ mean?

Comment: $\ell^2$ is the set of sequences $(a_n)$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2 < \infty$. The useful part for Hadamard's inequality is that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is $N$ such that $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} a_n^2 < \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There exists the following counterexample for the conjecture. Let $a_1=a_2=1$ and $n(1)=0$. Suppose that we already constructed the members $a_1,\dots,a_{2^{n(k)}+1}$ for some natural $k$. Let these members constitute the first row of the square matrix. Fill all entries of the first column of the matrix  but the first by zeroes. Finally, fill its bottom right corner by any [Hadamard_matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) of order $2^{n(k)}$, multiplied by $2^{-n(k)/2}$. Then the matrix will have the determinant $1$. Finally, pick any $n(k+1)$ such that
$2^{n(k)}+1$ is not smaller than the number $N$ of already determined members of the sequence $(a_n)$ and
put $a_{N+1}=\dots =a_{2^{n(k+1)}+1}=0$.

Comment: Nice construction, but why do you need $a_2=1$?

Comment: @user1551 Whoops! Thanks for the correction

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for your kind words. Right, we do not need $a_2=1$, but we need to assign to $a_2$ some value in order to stard the induction with $n(1)=0$.